# Perforce WSAECONNRESET Error

Tags: virtualbox, perforce

I'm getting the below "WSAECONNRESET" error when I try and connect with Perforce P4V on a VM I use.

"TCP receive failed.
read: socket: WSAECONNRESET"

This started late last week, it worked fine prior to that. I don't know of anything that has changed. The Perforce server is up and working because I can connect just fine from outside of the VM and other users aren't having any issues with it.

I can ping the server I'm trying to connect to from the VM just fine too. No firewalls are turned on. I have tried restarting the VM, my PC, and reinstalling Perforce (latest version). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that a few developers copied the same VM and we all had the same Mac Address. This didn't manifest in issues we noticed anywhere else, but Perforce couldn't handle it. Refreshing the Mac Address to eliminate this conflict resolved the previously mentioned Perforce errors.